# Concatenate folder of multiple newline-delimited JSON files into single file

Tags: json, concatenation, ndjson

We have a directory `/our_jsons` that has the files:

**file1.json**

```
{"team": 1, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the ballers"}
{"team": 2, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the hoopers"}
```

**file2.json**

```
{"team": 3, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the gamerrs"}
{"team": 4, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the drivers"}
```

**file3.json**

```
{"team": 5, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the jumpers"}
{"team": 6, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the riserss"}
```

and we need to stack these into a single file **output_file.json**, that simply has all of the JSONs in our directory combined / stacked on top of one another:

**output_file.json**

```
{"team": 1, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the ballers"}
{"team": 2, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the hoopers"}
{"team": 3, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the gamerrs"}
{"team": 4, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the drivers"}
{"team": 5, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the jumpers"}
{"team": 6, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the riserss"}
```

Is this possible to do with a bash command in Mac / Linux? We're hoping this is easier than combining ordinary JSONs because these are NDJSONs and so the files truly simply need to just be stacked on top of one-another. Our full data is much larger (~10GB of data split over 100+ newline-delimited JSONs), and we're hoping to find a decently-performant (under 2-5 minutes) solution if possible. I just installed and am reading docs on `jq` currently, and will update if we come up with a solution.

**EDIT:**

It looks like `jq . our_jsons/* > output_file.json` concats the JSONs, however the output is not an ND JSON but rather an ordinary (and invalid) JSON file...

Answer (score 2):

`cat tmp/* | jq -c '.' > tmp/output_file.json` appears to get the job done!

Comment: You may omit '.' as well: `cat tmp/* | jq -c  > tmp/output_file.json`